# I don't understand this ("string" == "string") example

Tags: java, string, equals

I found this java code on a java tutorial page:

```
if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName())
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html

How could this work? I thought we HAVE TO use the `equals()` method for this situation (`string.equals("bla")`)? Could we use `equals()` here too? Would it be better? Any ideas?

Edit: So IF `equals()` would be better, then I really don't understand why a **serious oracle tutorial page** didn't use it?  Also, I don't understand why it's working because I thought a string is an object.  If I say `object == object`, then that's a big problem.

Comment: Answer to your Edit, the literal "progress" is probably defined as static and final, and JVM maintains an internal pool of String literals and substitute similar string literals in compiled code with same reference. As other posters specified, it is not considered as a good practice to use == to compare string literals.

Comment: It does seem strange that you would find such a thing in an Oracle tutorial.  It just goes to show that other than me, you can't trust anyone.:)

Comment: +1 Sometimes Java is like English.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, equals() would definitely be better and correct. In Java, a pool of string constants is maintained and reused intelligently for performance. So this **can** work, but it is only guaranteed if evt.getPropertyName() is assured to return constants.

Also, the more correct version would be `"progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())`, in case `evt.getPropertyName()` is null. Note that the implementation of `String.equals` starts with using `==` as a first test before doing char-by-char comparison, so performance will not be much affected versus the original code.

Answer (score 2):

The correct version of this code should be:

```
if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName()))
```

This could work because of the way that the JVM handles string constants. Each string constant is [intern()ed](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html). So if evt.getPropertyName() is returning a reference to a string constant than using `==` will work. But it is bad form and in general it will not work.

Comment: Spike, if evt.getPropertyName is returning a reference to a string constant, it will *definitely* work.

Comment: @Jon Bright: The answer is correct in essence-- certainly it has the right code. Whoever downvoted this was way too harsh.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: I downvoted it for being technically wrong.  If Spike removes that "(probably)", I'll happily remove that vote.  Since the whole point of the question was to *clarify* the situation with == and equals, introducing technical inaccuracies strikes me as a good reason for a downvote in this case.  (I wouldn't be this picky if the question weren't on exactly this subject.)

Comment: @Jon Bright: I fixed it for Spike (sorry Spike) so that you'll remove your downvote. The fact that I just went in and edited the answer is a mark of how ridiculous I think the downvote is, so Spike I hope you won't be offended.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Downvote removed.  The answer was technically inaccurate in an area directly related to the question - I don't really see what the problem is with downvoting that.  Still, I hope we're all happy now.

Comment: @Azure don't be sorry. In the faq it specifically says `"If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."`

Comment: Hey hey no worries guys... I looked it up and the "probably" was a "definitely"... thanks to @Platinum Azure for the edit... just trying to be helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Which demo are we looking at?

This explains equals() vs ==

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221

> It is important to understand that the equals( ) method and the == operator perform two different operations. As just explained, the equals( ) method compares the characters inside a String object. The == operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance. The following program shows how two different String objects can contain the same characters, but references to these objects will not compare as equal:

So in your particular example, it is comparing the reference to see if they are the same reference, not to see if the string chars match I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This only would work if evt.getPropertyName() returns a constant string of value "progress".
With constant string, I mean evaluated at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, when comparing `String`s, using `equals` is best.  However, if you know you'll be comparing the exact same `String` objects (not just two strings that have the same content), or if you're dealing entirely with constant `String`s *and* you really care about performance, using `==` will be somewhat faster than using `equals`.  You should normally use `equals` since you normally don't care about performance sufficiently to think about all the other prerequisites for using `==`.

In this case, the author of [the progress demo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressMonitorDemoProject/src/components/ProgressMonitorDemo.java) should probably have used `equals` - that code isn't especially performance-critical.  However, in this particular case, the code will be dealing entirely with constant strings, so whilst it's probably not the best choice, especially for a demo, it is a valid choice.